# Перевести слово русского языка в другой падеж (PHP)

Tags: php, морфология

Есть слово в именительном падеже, единственном числе. Нужно перевести его в другой падеж и/или число. Для PHP.

Например:

- красный -> (мн. число) красные
- Олег -> (род. пад.) Олега
- Феодосия -> (предл. пад.) Феодосии
- (сложнее, так как только во мн. числе) Кижи -> (предл. падеж) Кижах

Нашел [phpMorphy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmorphy/). В целом работает. Но не справляется с Феодосией (считает, что это мужчина по имени Феодосий). Проект не развивается, непонятно, как обновить словари.

Что еще можно использовать для этой задачи?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, если Вам именно бесплатное решение нужно. [**Morpher**](http://morpher.ru/) Феодосию и Кижи правильно склоняет по крайней мере в [**веб-версии**](http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx). Но он платный. Ссылки: [**PHP-модуль**](http://morpher.ru/php/extension/), [**сравнение с аналогами на сайте Морфера**](http://morpher.ru/Competition/Default.aspx), [**сравнение с аналогами на Хабрахабре**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/304804/). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных В качестве ответа принимаются и платные решения тоже. Но Morpher распространяется в виде расширения php morpher.so, которое требуется устанавливать на сервер. Это сильно сужает возможности его использования.

Answer (score 3):

Решения на php я не нашел.

Зато нашел следующие альтернативы:

- [pymorphy2](https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2) - морфологический анализатор на python на базе словаря [OpenCorpora](http://opencorpora.org/)
- [Az.js](https://github.com/deNULL/Az.js) - основанная на pymorphy2 реализация на nodejs.

В итоге я написал консольный скрипт на JS, который переводит слово в нужную форму. Скрипт вызываю из PHP через `exec()`, работает долго, поэтому результаты кеширую.

Для достижения хорошего результата скрипту также приходится указывать исходную форму слова, иначе возможно, что вместо существительного "пень" будет возвращен глагол "пенить".

Вот пример работы скрипта:

```
$ node ./az.js красный nomn plur Олег nomn gent Феодосия nomn loct Кижи nomn loct
красные
олега
феодосии
кижах
```

Вот сам скрипт (извините, на JS пишу как умею):

```
"use strict";

var tasks = [];

// Принимаем аргументы в формате:
//
// СЛОВО ИСХОДНАЯ_ФОРМА ТРЕБУЕМАЯ_ФОРМА [ СЛОВО ИСХОДНАЯ_ФОРМА ТРЕБУЕМАЯ_ФОРМА ... ]
//
// Для каждого запрошенного слова выводит результат в виде нужной формы или пустой строки,
// если преобразовать не получилось.
// Исходная/требуемая форма задается в виде набора граммем через запятую.
// Граммемы: http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=gram
//
// Пример:
//   node ./az.js пень NOUN,nomn datv,plur Феодосия Geox loct
//
// Переводит слово "пень", которое является существительным (NOUN) (а не глаголом "пенить")
// в именительном падеже (nomn) в дательный падеж (datv) мн. число (plur) --> "пням".
// А также переводит "Феодосия" (город Geox, а не мужское имя Феодосий) к предложному
// падежу --> "Феодосии"
//
// Выводит результат на 2 строчках:
//
// пням
// феодосии
//

// Разбираем аргументы
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
    // первые два аргумента - node и script
    if (index < 2) return;

    // номер блока из 3 аргументов (слово, исходная, требуемая) (zero-based)
    var block = Math.floor((index + 1) / 3 - 1);
    // номер аргумента в блоке (zero-based)
    var arg = (index + 1) % 3;

    if (typeof tasks[block] === "undefined") {
        tasks[block] = { word: null, form: null, inForm: null };
    }

    if (arg == 0) {
        // слово
        tasks[block].word = val;
    } else if (arg == 1) {
      // исходная форма
        tasks[block].inForm = val.split(",");
    } else {
      // требуемая форма
        tasks[block].form = val.split(",");
    }
});

var Az = require('az');

Az.Morph.init(function() {

    // выводим результат построчно
    solveTasks(tasks).every(elem => console.log(elem) || true);

    function solveTasks(tasks) {

        var result = [];

        tasks.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
            // морфологический разбор
            var parses = Az.Morph(val.word, { stutter: false});

            // ищем в вариантах слово в нужной форме
            var word = null;
            for (var i in parses) {
                // console.log(parses[i].word);
                // console.log(parses[i].tag);
                // Если tag содержит все граммемы, которые присутствовали в inForm,
                // значит это наше слово.
                if (arrayContainsArray(Object.keys(parses[i].tag), val.inForm)) {
                    // нашли
                    word = parses[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!word) {
                // не нашли
                result.push("");
                // result.push(val.word);
            } else {
                // нашли
                result.push(word.inflect(val.form).word);
            }

        });

        return result;
    }

    function arrayContainsArray(bigger, smaller) {
        // возвращает true, если все элементы массива smaller присутствуют в bigger
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514907/determining-whether-one-array-contains-the-contents-of-another-array-in-javascri
        return smaller.every(elem => bigger.indexOf(elem) > -1);
    }
});
```